# P8Z58 - Disabling turbo mode

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, overclocking

I have a P8Z68 DELUXE /GEN3 motherboard with a Core i7 2700K CPU rated to go to 3.5GHz.
I want to know how to disable Turbo mode in the bios cause my pc seems to go from 3.5Ghz to 3.9 under load and I want it to stick to 3.5Ghz because its causing stability issues where my pc restarts from time to time when under load. How can I tell the bios not to overclock my cpu? That is I do not want *any* overclocking at all.

Comment: It's a hardware fault, you should RMA your MoBo or CPU (or maybe PSU) if possible (check which one causes the problem first). Disabling Turbo Boost is a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. the cpu is only suppose to go to 3.5 its going to 3.9ish because the bios overclocked it to such. In the meantime ive fixed it by modifying the advanced power options in the control panel and set it to only use 80% of CPU. That way its only goes to 3.4 ish or such. So far so good. I'd prefer to fix it in the bios though.

Comment: Turbo Boost is not a BIOS's overclocking feature, it's a CPU feature guaranteed to work by Intel.

Comment: RMAing is not an option. The hardware is no longer under any warranty or gaurantee. Is there any way to turn it off? (Regardless of whether it is faulty or not)

Comment: I don't know how it's called in your BIOS, but you should look for anything that sounds like overclocking-related. In my laptop's BIOS it's called "Easy overclock" or something like that.